# Empty callstack during debug in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: php, xdebug, netbeans-8

I have configured Netbeans 8.2 in order to use it with xdebug.
If I enable  "stop after first line" option from Preference > PHP > debugging tab, I see the callstack tab is populated by index.php of my project.

Instead when I disable the same option, the callstack tab remains empty.

I already checked port used for debugging, and it's open.
This is the configuration in my php.ini

```
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

How can I solve this?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the reason of my issue. I just added a breakpoint before the first function call, so the callStack was not populated. Thanks anyway